# Question text disappears when I go to edit it

Tags: support, edits, editor

> **In order to preserve this state, please don't commit any edits to this question.**

The question [Reset AutoNumber(Identity Field) in Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463417/reset-autonumberidentity-field-in-database) begins with the text, "Hi All", but the editor strips seems to strip it out:

> ***Post:***[image]
>
> ***Editor:***[image]

Are greetings stripped from posts automagically nowadays? Or is this a bug that the text differs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, we strip the greetings, a system that was put in place since that post was last edited.  The behavior is intentional.